# por que al poner cualquier dia me suelta CORRECTO

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
$num1=0; $num2=0; $num3=0; $num4="";
if (isset($_POST["btnCalcular"])) {
    $num1=$_POST["txtnum1"];
    $num2=$_POST["txtnum2"];
    $num3=$_POST["txtnum3"];
    $num4=$_POST["txtnum4"];    

    switch ($num1) {
        case '1':
            if($num2>0 && $num2<32){
                $num4="CORRECTO";
             }              
            break;
        case '2':
            if($num2%4==0 && $num2%400==0){
                $num4="CORRECTO";
            }           
            break;
        case '3':
            if($num2>0 && $num2<32){
                $num4="CORRECTO";
            }
            break;
        case '4':
            if($num2>0 && $num2<31){
                $num4="CORRECTO";
            }
            break;
        case '5':
            if($num2>0 && $num2<32){
                $num4="CORRECTO";
            }
            break;
        case '6':
            if($num2>0 && $num2<31){
                $num4="CORRECTO";
            }
            break;                  
        case '7':
            if($num2>0 && $num2<32){
                $num4="CORRECTO";
            }
            break;
        case '8':
            if($num2>0 && $num2<32){
                $num4="CORRECTO";
            }
            break;  
        case '9':
            if($num2>0 && $num2<32){
                $num4="CORRECTO";
            }
            break;
        case '10':
            if($num2>0 && $num2<31){
                $num4="CORRECTO";
             }
            break;
        case '11':
            if($num2>0 && $num2<31){
                $num4="CORRECTO";
            }
            break;
        case '12':
            if($num2>0 && $num2<32){
                $num4="CORRECTO";
            }
            break;                              
        default:
            $num4="INCORRECTO";
            break;
            }
    }
?>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="7.php"><table>
    <tr>
    <td>Mes</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtnum1" id="txtnum1" value="<?=$num1?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Dia</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtnum2" id="txtnum2" value="<?=$num2?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Año</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtnum3" id="txtnum3" value="<?=$num3?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Respuesta</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtnum4" id="txtnum4" value="<?=$num4?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="btnCalcular" id="btnCalcular" value="Calcular"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cuando vale $num2?

Comment: num1 es es el mes y num 2 es el dia

Answer (score 0):

a mi si me funciono el código.

Te mando uno mas sencillo que tambien me funcionó.

Las variables **$num1** y **$num2** deben ser numéricas.

```
// Definimos el máximo de días de cada mes
$dias_arr=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];

// Si el mes ($num1) es entre 1 y 12 entramos avalidar el día ($num2)
if ( $num1=1 && $num1<=12 ) {

// Validamos si el dia ($num2) esta en el rango de días del mes ($num1)
    if ( $num2>=1 && $num2<=$dias_arr[$num1] ) {

// Si cumple las condiciones anteriores es correcto el día
        $num4="CORRECTO";

    }
}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si `$num4` sólo puede tomar dos valores: CORRECTO e INCORRECTO, entonces debieras inicializarlo como "INCORRECTO".

```
if (isset($_POST["btnCalcular"])) {
    $num1=$_POST["txtnum1"];
    $num2=$_POST["txtnum2"];
    $num3=$_POST["txtnum3"];
    $num4='INCORRECTO';   

    switch ($num1) {


    }

}
```

Puesto que si el mes está entre 1 y 12, entrará a un bucle del tipo

```
case '3':
  if($num2>0 && $num2<32){
     $num4="CORRECTO";
  }
break;
```

Luego si `$num2 = 33`, entonces `$num4` no se verá alterado y por tanto conservará el valor que venga de `$num4=$_POST["txtnum4"];` y eso no es lo que buscas

Con el cambio que te digo, la respuesta partirá siendo INCORRECTO y sólo cambiará si se cumplen las condiciones para que sea correcto.